# Comparing two rows, one from one table and where it doesn't match in another

Tags: sql-server, compare, rows

If I have table `dbo.PortsBaselineTable` and `dbo.PortsTable`

Each have the exact same column names:

```
[Date],[Plant],[ComputerName],[Protocol],[LocalAddress],[LocalPort],[RemoteAddress],[RemotePort],[State],[ProcessName],[Baseline]
```

I want to be able to query the resulting differences.  The dbo.PortsBaselineTable will have about 6000 rows and the Baseline Column will have the number '1', the dbo.PortsTable will continually add data and the Baseline Column will have '0' for all rows.  I want to pick two dates one from each table and compare all the rows that are different based on the two particular dates and then grouped by computer name.

Is this even feasible?  I would mind having the data in the same table with just the baseline flag changing as I add more data.

Here is a snapshot of the result set:

```
        Date    Plant   ComputerName    Protocol    LocalAddress    LocalPort   RemoteAddress   RemotePort  State   ProcessName Baseline
2014-01-30 07:52:58 plantname   COMPUTERNAME    TCP 10.10.40.100    49157   192.168.0.2 64807   ESTABLISHED lsass   1
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using EXCEPT? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx